# Correct way to use SharePoint to share and document program code?

Tags: sharepoint-online, development

We are a software company and are trying to use Office 365 SharePoint Site Pages for internal wiki and document sharing which obviously would contain quite some code snippets.

However the issue with SharePoint site pages is that whenever we try to copy and paste the code snippets from there in IDE or in terminal window they DON'T work because some of the bytes and characters are in UTF8.

We had to manually type the code snippets again which is really annoying.

For example, on [this page](https://datactory.sharepoint.com/Datactorycom/SitePages/%E6%8C%82%E8%BD%BD%E6%95%B0%E6%8D%AE%E5%BA%93.aspx), slash / is in UTF8 and when the path is pasted in a terminal window the server doesn't recognize it at all.

My question is, is there any way to enforce ASCII encoding for a snippet of text / content in SharePoint site pages?

Or is there any intended way to share and document program code in Office 365 with ACL and wiki style editing and interconnecting capabilities?

## UPDATE

We tried **Insert** > **Embed Code** but the code snippets still contain UTF8 characters here and there in a random manner - may be layout control characters or something?